# How do I open a shell but still have access to vim

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, vim

I am running gvim on Windows 7.

I use this mapping to execute the current file with powershell:

```
nnoremap <C-q> :! & '%:p'<cr>
```

It works great except I can't access vim until I close the powershell window. Sometimes I want the shell to remain open so I can run additional commands or I want to access vim with the shell still open so I can check the lines where errors were generated.

Ideally (don't know if this is possible) I want to have an already open shell execute the command. So I always have vim and a shell open (on separate monitors) and I can execute the script in that same shell.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use another window? I know that's a bit basic, but...

Comment: You mean switch to an already open shell manually and run the script? I could do that, but then I would need to copy/enter the path of the script I'm working on every time. Its super convenient to have little hotkey that just executes the current file! especially if I have multiple buffers open with different scripts I'm working on in different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GVIM on Windows has a special `:!start` command to execute the external command asynchronously; i.e. Vim doesn't wait for its return. Just replace the `:!` with it. See `:help :!start` for more information.

On Unix, such special isn't necessary; you can just append `&` (a shell feature) to execute the command asynchronously.

Comment: That seems like exactly what I want, but I don't think I'm doing this right. I tried editing my mapping to this: `nnoremap <C-q> :!start & '%:p'<cr>` but when I run it I get `E371: Command not found`

Comment: I see it; Vim seems to use a different way to launch the command. Try `:!start powershell.exe & '%:p'`; it seems that the value of `'shell'` isn't used here.

Comment: That works! I still can't access the shell after the commands runs though and I have to put a pause in the script or it will close immediately, but I guess there's nothing I can do about that.

Comment: This might be more a powershell question than a vim question, but I was wondering if there is a way to always include a pause (without having to put a pause statement in the actual script I'm running). The noexit switch isn't working: `nnoremap <C-q> :!start powershell & '%:p' -noexit<cr>`

Comment: I got it! `nnoremap <C-q> :!start powershell.exe -noexit -command "& '%:p'"<cr>` This leaves the shell open after the command runs, exactly what I want. Thanks a lot for your help.